# Pass method name as parameter to another method

Tags: ruby

I want to pass a method name, not a block, as a parameter to another method to use as a callback:

```
def one(param)
  puts param
end

def two(param, &callback)
  callback.call(param)
end

two('hi', :one)
```

Is this possible? I tried it and got an error saying I passed two parameters but only one was expected.

Comment: Only one was expected because &callback isn't a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `send`:

```
def two(param, callback)
  send(callback, param)
end
```

Comment: Please, use `public_send` instead.

Answer (score 4):

While @JohnNaegle's answer is correct, I find this a slightly more elegant way to do this is using `#method`, which returns a `Method` object. The method object has a `.call(*args)` method, though which you can pass arguments. So, with your example it would look like:

```
def one(param)
  puts param
end

def two(param, callback)
  callback.call(param)
end

two('hi', method(:one))
```

The change is that you are passing a reference to an instance of `Method` by calling `Object.method` (same thing as `method`) rather than a string.

If you want to pass a symbol instead of a `Method` you could use the following version of `#two`:

```
def two_2(param, callback)
  method(callback.to_sym).call(param)
end

two_2('hi', :one)
# Or you could also pass a string or anything that #responds_to?(:to_sym)
two_2('hi', 'one')
```

A further improvement I would recommend, so that `two` can accept more than one parameter to pass to the callback would be listing the callback first then using `*params` to receive as many parameters as necessary. Here is an example (using definition of `#one` from above):

```
def one_with_many_params(*params)
  puts params.join
end

# Improved version of two
def two_3(callback, *params)
  callback.call(params)
end

# Improved version of two_2
def two_4(callback, *params)
  method(callback.to_sym).call(params)
end

two_3(method(:one), 'hi') #=> "hi"
two_3(method(:one_with_many_params), "Hi", " my ", "name", " is ", "Foo!")
#=> "Hi my name is Foo!"

two_4('one', 'Hello!') #=> "Hello!"
two_4(:one_with_many_params, "Hi", " my ", "name", " is ", "Bar!")
#=> "Hi my name is Bar!"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send the *name* of a method, then, yes, a symbol is the correct form for that, as John's answer points out (and you can then use send to call that method). But, if you want, you can also send *the method itself*:

```
def one(param)
  puts param
end

def two(param, &callback)
  callback.call(param)
end

one_method = method(:one)
two('hi', &one_method)
```

The advantage of that way of doing things is that you can do it when a method is expecting a block, without (as `two` does) without having to change the method definition. You also can pass in methods from different objects, whereas with send if you want to call the method on a different object you'd also have to pass in who you want to call it on (or figure that out in some other way):

```
class Foo
  def one(param)
    puts param
  end
end

class Bar
  def two(param, &callback)
    callback.call(param)
  end
end

f = Foo.new
b = Bar.new
b.two('hi') {|param| puts param } # with a block
b.two('hi', &f.method(:one)) # with a Method object
```